# fatal: cannot update the ref 'HEAD': unable to append to '.git/logs/HEAD': Bad file descriptor

Tags: github, git-commit, git

I am working on Robot framework Automation project. All of a sudden git commit does not work I get below error on commit command

```
**fatal: cannot update the ref 'HEAD': unable to append to '.git/logs/HEAD': Bad file descriptor**
```

I am working on Windows machine. I have done 4 commits till now and code is in Repo. With the latest changes, commit is not happening with above error I have gone through few issues quoted in stack-overflow regarding this but I could get it resolved.

Please help me in overcoming this issue

I use the command `git commit -a -m "description"` or `git commit -m "description"`

None of the sudo command work for me it says

```
> $ sudo chown -R useremail .git/ 
> bash: sudo: command not found
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354928/bash-sudo-command-not-found/354936 sounds like you're missing sudo.

Comment: The *I am working on Windows machine* part suggests to me that you've run into the famous (infamous?) problem where Windows systems refuse to let programs open any file that some *other* program already has open. In that case, find the other program that is holding your Git files open, and terminate it (or wait for it to finish).

Comment: none of the options worked except one thing i.e., cloning and pushing code from c drive i could only work in c drive whereas in other drives i am unable to clone or pull or push the code

Comment: Thanks for the response. But i could find one solution i.e., GIT version 2.19.1 has caused the issue. When i downgraded the git version it was working fine.

Comment: The problem also occurs when trying to sync with cloud services.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen when you accidently create a branch with root permission. Its best to check .git locally for ownership permissions i.e. ls -la .git/refs/heads/ should be owned by the user and not root.

Answer (score -1):

Try the same command with:

- a regular CMD session (no Git bash or Cygwin)
- the latest [Git for Windows 2.21](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.21.0.windows.1)
- a new clone repo

You should not experience that bug again.